# Getting values from a text editor in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

I'm using a quill js component (a text editor) for Reactjs and I'm testing it to see all it's features.

I managed to build a editor with a toolbar, but now I have a doubt, how can I get everything the user typed and save it in my state? As I'll show you in the code if I console.log(the quillRef.current) I get a div and way inside it I have a p element which contains everything the user has typed. My idea is to place a button in the end, and when the user stops typing and clicks the button I store what they typed.

here's a link to the sandbox where I'm testing it:
[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quilljsbasic-x4qid?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `quill.getText()` function :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { useQuill } from "react-quilljs";

export default () => {
  const { quill, quillRef } = useQuill();
  const [savedText, setSavedText] = useState("");

  const handleSave = () => {
    const text = quill.getText();
    setSavedText(text);
  };


  return (
    <div style={{ width: 500, height: 300 }}>
      <button onClick={handleSave}>SAVE</button>
      <div>Saved State : {savedText}</div>
      <div ref={quillRef} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Check on codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quilljsbasic-tt6pm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Is there a way to get this data with the styles applied by the user?

Comment: I dont know , you need to check library and documentation closely : https://github.com/gtgalone/react-quilljs

Comment: @GabrielTiso The styles are already imported in `quill/dist/quill.snow.css`  and all you need to do is have the class name `className="ql-editor"` in the div where you will render the generated html and all the styles will apply immediately